# Bottom container stacking ontop of middle container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have two containers.  One of the containers has two divs stacking ontop of each other (a img and text).  That is fine.  But it seems the bottom container is stacking ontop of the 1st container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id='map'>
    <div id='image'>
      <img src="/static/usa.png">
    </div>
    <div id='states'>
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <center>
        <h2>Select Your State</h2>
      Select your state from the list below to find information specific to your area.
      </center>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        state
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        state
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        state
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        state
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        state
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        state
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <center>
  <h1>Information on ...</h1>
    This site is a beta framework

  </center>
</div>
```

and my css file is

```
img {
    width:100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

#map { position: relative; }
#image {position: absolute;}
#states {
    position: absolute;
}


span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;}

a {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. Also, positioning is a **very** poor layout option...try removing it.

Comment: @Paulie_D replaced ```center``` with ```text-center```, what you shuggest i replace position with to get the same affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it by instead of trying to stack the images just setting it to a background image static.

```
body {
    background-image: url("/static/usa.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `clear:both;` to the bottom container